# RSpec with Devise: subject.current_user is nil when used in second method in a context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am currently using RSpec to test my Rails 4 application and when testing, I found this strange problem: subject.current_user is nil in the second method in a context. Code snippet:

```
  describe 'GET #register_as_team:' do
    context 'user logged in but not admin:' do
      login_user
      it 'should redirect_to user_path if user is not student' do
        get :register_as_team, id: subject.current_user.id
        expect(response).to redirect_to(user_path(subject.current_user))
        expect(flash[:danger]).not_to be_nil
      end

      it 'should redirect_to student_path if user is a non-pending student' do
        student = FactoryGirl.create(:student, user: subject.current_user, is_pending: false)
        get :register_as_team, id: subject.current_user.id
        expect(response).to redirect_to(student_path(student))
      end
    end
  end
```

So when `subject.current_user` is used first time, it is OK and I can just get the logged user but in the second method it returns nil.

For background information, `login_user` is like this:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user(user = nil)
    before(:each) do
      # @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user ||= User.find_by(email: 'default_user@controller.spec')
      user ||= FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: 'default_user@controller.spec', uid: 'default_user.controller.spec')
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In an example, `subject` can only be [resolved once](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/subject/explicit-subject#subject-block-is-invoked-at-most-once-per-example).
When you did, `get :register_as_team, id: subject.current_user.id`, you essentially resolved `subject` already and `subject.current_user` is not resolved in next line.

Try this:

```
  describe 'GET #register_as_team:' do
    context 'user logged in but not admin:' do
      login_user
      it 'should redirect_to user_path if user is not student' do
        user = subject.current_user
        get :register_as_team, id: user.id
        expect(response).to redirect_to(user_path(user))
        expect(flash[:danger]).not_to be_nil
      end

  it 'should redirect_to student_path if user is a non-pending student' do
    student = FactoryGirl.create(:student, user: subject.current_user, is_pending: false)
    user = subject.current_user
    get :register_as_team, id: user.id
    expect(response).to redirect_to(student_path(student))
  end
end
```